# get product variation parent product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

How I can get variation parent product ID.

EXAMPLE:
I have product with ID 35
and this product has two variations colors - red (ID 351), black (ID 352)

My code:
 `$product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID()); //get_the_ID() is ID 351 and I need this parent ID 35`

Comment: use `$product->get_parent_id()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The proper way

As LoicTheAztec suggested in comments, you should use this:

```php
$parent_product = wc_get_product($product->get_parent_id());
```

The reason why you should retrieve parent product via `get_parent_id()` is that it will trigger hook `woocommerce_product_variation_get_parent_id` and it will be easily modifiable by other plugins/themes:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_parent_id', function($value, $wc_data) {
    // ...
    return $value;
}, 10, 2);
```

This will also work, but it won't trigger WC-specific hooks:

```php
$parent_product_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($product->get_id());
$parent_product = wc_get_product($parent_product_id);
```

### Old answer

*Note: That's not working outside the loop and will always return `0` if you attempt to substitute `get_the_ID()` with `$product->id` - in that case use `$product->get_id()` as in the example above.*

Use `wp_get_post_parent_id`, as variations have their parent as the product itself.

Example:

```php
$variation_id = get_the_ID();
$product_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($variation_id);
```

---

Never use [WC_Product::get_parent()](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wc_productget_parent-is-deprecated1-since-version-3-0/):

```php
$parent_product = $product->get_parent(); // will always return '0
```

Comment: It is not working, tried like this: `$variation_id = get_the_ID();
$product_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($variation_id);
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);` and I have in my template this variable: `$product->get_price_html();` and it is giving error: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on bool`

Comment: nevermind your code works but it is not fixing issue for my problem. I asked wrong thing :/

Comment: You need to check what is in $product_id `$product` would be an object.

Comment: Im using ACF and it is not giving parent product fields to variation product...